# view file for Ruby on Rails with dropdown box inexplicably not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I've created two models, one is bar, one is special. I've created a dropdown box in my new special view file that I want to display bars. Here is my code.

```
<%= form_for(@special) do |f| %>
<% if @special.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@special.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this special from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
   <% @special.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>      <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :special %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :special %> 
 </div>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.collection_select(:special, :bar_id, Bar.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a bar" %>  
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Sorry for the poor formatting above. What I get when I run this code is this:

> Showing D:/DevProjects/tapadeal/app/views/specials/_form.html.erb
>   where line #24 raised:
>
> D:/DevProjects/tapadeal/app/views/specials/_form.html.erb:24: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '); end 
>          ^ D:/DevProjects/tapadeal/app/views/specials/_form.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
>   D:/DevProjects/tapadeal/app/views/specials/_form.html.erb:28: syntax
>   error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' Extracted source (around
>   line #24):
>
> Extracted source (around line #24):
>
> 21:   div class="actions"
>
> 22:     <%= f.submit %>
>
> 23:   /div
>
> 24: <% end %>

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing your parentheses:

```
 <%= f.collection_select(:special, :bar_id, Bar.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a bar") %>
```